# Exterminate the Death Claws in Original Fallout

Tags: fallout

I've killed the death claw mother in the quest to help the Gun Runners in Boneyard. They promised they would move out and leave behind a huge stockpile of ammunition as a reward. **They have done no such thing.** Is this a glitch?

Upon talking to Gabriel and saying I've killed all the deathclaws and asking for the weapons, all of the Gun runners start aimlessly walking about the place, but that's it.

Where is the stockpile of weapons located? Could someone mark on this image?

[image]

It's not every clear in the game at all.

It's not made clear in this article?

Maybe I should do the 'get weapons for the blades' quest to open up the dialogue options with Gabriel again?

Also, when I talk to Gabriel I can still say 'I think I've killed all the Deathclaws', to which he responds 'Wait a few days, we've killed 20 over the past 2 years'. I wait a few days. No death claws come back because I've killed the mother and when I talk to Gabriel all I can say is 'I think I've killed all the Deathclaws' and so on ad infinitum.

That's what makes me think it's a glitch.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly the Gun Runners by the stock mean the guns located in the same place in the cabinets/chests. Just loot them. If they started to walk around then I think that means they will soon move from the place. However due to bad pathfinding it just takes longer time.

Comment: Hopefully you're right! What do you make of my edit? Also I think you're right about the path finding, but they're not leaving at all! Literally just wandering (it's been weeks of in-game time) which again makes me think it's getting all gltichy.

Comment: Did you destroyed the eggs and other deathclaws?

Comment: Yep! Gabriel thanked me and said I could help myself to all the guns and didn't show me where they were and whenever I talk to him the above just happens.

Comment: Like Balen said, there are some lockers in the same room where Gabriel is standing. Make sure you have a lot of room in your inventory before raiding them.